# Hibernate getting only column1 from a query returning multiple columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a query of this nature

```
String query = select column1, group by column2 from table1 ...
//What should I write to just get column1 from the query.       
getSession().createQuery(query).list();
```

How do I get just columne1 list from the query.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with this question ?

Comment: In my select result I have a list of column1 and group by column2 results, how do i get only column1 results. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

With hibernate HQL/JPQL queries you don't get get columns. You get objects and their properties. So:

```
String query = "SELECT yourEntity.property1 FROM yourEntity .....";
```

Then the `list()` will return a `List<Foo>`, where `Foo` is the type of `property1`

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this in Hibernate String query = "Select entity.proprety1, entity.property2 from entity" ; and the list() return results and I am only interested in List<Foo>

Comment: if you don't want a property, don't include it in the select list

Comment: If the query is select property1, group by (property2) ... but only interested on property1 , Is it not possible then

Comment: if propety2 is only present in the group by clause you'll have it working as you want. Try it.